# Is there a way to modify class attributes in static methods used in template decorator?

Tags: c++, templates, decorator

I am studying Cpp templates and experimenting how to implement a decorator like functionality so that when I call `log.warn` some extra code is executed on top off the `warn` method, thus resulting in an extra behavior added to the method without actually overriding it.

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename Func>
struct Decorator {
    Func* func;
    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args... args) {
        printf("Before function execution\n");
        (*func)(args...);
        printf("After function execution\n");   
    }
};

class Logger{
    private:
        int val= 0;
        static void warn(char * str, char * ptr){
            printf("Inside warn()\n");
            printf("%s %s\n", str, ptr);
        }
        void info(){printf("Inside info()\n");}
    public:
        Decorator<decltype(warn)> decoratedWarn{warn};
        int get_val(){return val;}
};

int main(){
    char str[6] = "hello";
    char ptr[6] = "world";
    Logger log;
    log.decoratedWarn(str, ptr);
    printf("%d\n", log.get_val());
    return 0;
}
```

The goal behind such approach is to print the time before warn is actually called.
The other goal which I can't seem to figure out is how to modify the values of the class attributes such as `val` in the static function so that `val` is incremented every time `warn` is called.

Comment: DO you want `warn` to affect all `Logger`s or only a single one?  If it's that later, just make it a regular member function.

Comment: `val` is a non-static member. You need an instance to modify a non-static member. You can do that in a static method, but the instance has to come from somewhere (it cannot be `this` because there is no `this` in a static method)

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike what do you mean by all `Logger`s, are you referring to the objects or attributes of single object?

Comment: Do you want all instances of the class `Logger` to be affected when you call `warn` or do you only want one specific instance to be affected?

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that, in order to increment the `val` in `Decorator`, you need an instance in `Decorator` availabe. This enables you calling the increment function which you may provide.

However, there are multiple ways to achive this. The one in your own answer that you posted is tedious, becuase it requres each time the `log` instance to be passed to `Decorator::operator()`.

```
log.decoratedWarn(str, ptr, &log);
```

I would have avoided it by, letting the `Logger` be houskeeping own members. Follwoing is an example C++20 code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

template <auto Func, typename Instance>
class Decorator
{
    Instance* mInstance{ nullptr };
public:
    explicit Decorator(Instance* object)
        : mInstance{ object }
    {}

    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args)
    {
        printf("Before function execution\n");
        Func(mInstance, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        printf("After function execution\n");
    }
};

class Logger 
{
private:
    int val = 0;

    static void warn(Logger* self, char* str, char* ptr) {
        printf("Inside warn()\n");
        printf("%s %s\n", str, ptr);
        self->val++; // Increment the class attribute
    }

    void info() {
        printf("Inside info()\n");
    }

public:
    Decorator<&Logger::warn, Logger> decoratedWarn{ this };

    int get_val() 
    {
        return val;
    }
};

int main()
{
    char str[6] = "hello";
    char ptr[6] = "world";
    Logger log;
    log.decoratedWarn(str, ptr);
    printf("%d\n", log.get_val());  // 1

    log.decoratedWarn(str, ptr);
    printf("%d\n", log.get_val()); // 2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I prefer not to include other utilities and extra code but can't say no to such solution

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by 463035818_is_not_an_ai this can be achieved by passing the current object instance as an argument to the method the end result would become

```
class Logger{
    private:
        int val= 0;
        static void warn(char * str, char * ptr, Logger * log){
            printf("Inside warn()\n");
            printf("%s %s\n", str, ptr);
            log->val +=1;
        }
        void info(){printf("Inside info()\n");}
    public:
        Decorator<decltype(warn)> decoratedWarn{warn};
        int get_val(){return val;}
};

int main(){
    char str[6] = "hello";
    char ptr[6] = "world";
    Logger log;
    log.decoratedWarn(str, ptr, &log);
    printf("%d\n", log.get_val());
    return 0;
}
```

by changing `warn(char * str, char * ptr)` to `warn(char * str, char * ptr, Logger * log)` and calling the method as `log.decoratorWarn(str, ptr, &log)`.